# Spring Batch Need to schedule / run a job with for a period of a year on weekly basis

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, spring-batch, schedule

I have a an API that returns customer data based on date eg:

```
/customer?startdate=20180909&endDate=20181010.
```

Now these API returns huge data which I need to store in DB.

I have written a Spring batch to get the API data and store in DB.

My question is this
I want this job to be triggered in a dynamic value say 6 months, 1 year, 2 year.
Upon receiving this the job should be triggered weekly until the date is reached.
I mean if I trigger it for 6 months, the job should fetch data weekly untill the date 6 months before is reached

I tries several combinations with schedule but it didnt work Please guide here

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about using partitioner. masterStep does fetch weekly data and store in DB. And partitioning with week unit.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done using cron expression

@Scheduled(cron = "[Seconds] [Minutes] [Hours] [Day of month] [Month] [Day of week] [Year]")

@Scheduled(cron = "0 10 8 ? 1-6 L 2018")

here L means last day of the week. Normally its considered as saturday

Comment: Can we use this Scheduled on the fly.
as in for 6 month, 1 year 2 year based on parameter.

Comment: i didnt get what you said, please explain it little bit more